CKEditor 4: Open Link in new Tab
Craft 5 // CKEditor 4
I'm really missing an option to open a link in a new Tab.

an external link should open in a new tab by default
sometimes the redacteur needs to have the option to open an entry in a new tab
open an asset (pdf) in a new tab

Even a dirty workaround is not possible: Set target="_blank" within the code -> it'll be filtered out after saving.
Do you have any good idea for this?

"link": {
    "decorators": {
      "isExternal": {
        "attributes": {
          "rel": "noopener noreferrer",
          "target": "_blank"
        },
        "label": "Open in a new tab",
        "mode": "manual"
      }
    }
  },


Whow ... this works :)

Thanks a lot, Ilja!

Just to add to this, here's the official documentation: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/link.html#adding-attributes-to-links-using-the-ui-manual-decorators
